# AngularJS / Firebase - Need to login twice for a successful login

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase-security, angularjs-digest

I have simple AngularJS app and using Firebase OpenAuth for user authentication. Here is a sample code from plunkr.

```
  [http://plnkr.co/edit/ZVfkaJF0g3E5u63J7uHx?p=preview][1]
```

I have to click twice to authData from Google. I don't understand, why I can't get the data on the first click.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to apply `digest` cycle after receiving an event.

```
$rootScope.$auth.$onAuth(function(authData){
     $rootScope.authData = authData;
     $scope.$apply();
});
```

[**Forked Plunkr**](http://plnkr.co/edit/FbB9DrvbQyuEsAMuAnie?p=preview)