# Firebase Twitter login but no AuthData on callback

Tags: angularjs, firebase, angularfire

My button triggers the TwitterAuth function,

```
<div ng-controller="HomePage">
    <h1>New Home Page</h1>
    <button ng-click="TwitterAuth()">Log In</button>
    <button ng-click="logOut()">Log Out</button>
    {{authData}}
</div>
```

I get redirected to twitter, I login just fine and then get redirected back to the same page but the URL now is

```
http://www.mypage.com/?__firebase_request_key="xJhS4ObQtpzUdbJdIESkQKZJqZ3C51t1"
```

And no further refreshes or URL changes occur. I feel this could be the problem, maybe?

I am using Node Express to create a SPA.

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

var cacheTime = 86400000*365;    // one year

app.use('/img/icons', express.static(__dirname + '/public/img/icons',{ maxAge: cacheTime }));
app.use('/img', express.static(__dirname + '/public/img',{ maxAge: cacheTime }));
app.use('/templates', express.static(__dirname + '/public/templates',{ maxAge: cacheTime }));
app.use('/js', express.static(__dirname + '/public/js',{ maxAge: cacheTime }));
app.use('/css', express.static(__dirname + '/public/css',{ maxAge: cacheTime }));
app.use('/partials', express.static(__dirname + '/public/partials',{ maxAge: cacheTime }));

app.all('/*', function(req, res, next) {
    res.sendFile('/public/index.html', { root: __dirname });
});

 app.listen(8080);
```

Then I'm using Angular's Routes with html5Mode, I have tried with html5Mode disabled and it makes no difference.

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['ngRoute', "firebase"])

app.config(function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
    $routeProvider.
    when('/', {
        templateUrl: 'templates/home.html',
        controller: 'HomePage'
    }).
    when('/test/:countryName', {
        template: '<h1>TODO create country detail view</h1>',
        controller: 'HomePage2'
    }).
    otherwise({
         redirectTo: '/'
    });
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
});
```

The page doesn't refresh again and the page doesn't show the $scope.authData on the page or in the console.

```
app.factory("Auth", ["$firebaseAuth",
  function($firebaseAuth) {
    var ref = new Firebase("https://1212.firebaseio.com");
    return $firebaseAuth(ref);
  }
]);



app.controller("HomePage", ["$scope", "Auth", function ($scope, Auth) {

    $scope.auth = Auth;
    // any time auth status updates, add the user data to scope
    $scope.auth.$onAuth(function (authData) {
        $scope.authData = authData;
        console.log($scope.authData);
    });
```

If I use authWithOAuthPopUp then it works fine, but I dont really like the popup and would prefer a full page redirect.

```
            $scope.TwitterAuth = function () {
        var ref = new Firebase("https://1212.firebaseio.com");
        ref.authWithOAuthRedirect("twitter", function (error) {
            if (error) {
                console.log("Authentication Failed!", error);
            } else {
                // We'll never get here, as the page will redirect on success.
            }
        });
    }



    $scope.logOut = function (user) {
        var ref = new Firebase("https://1212.firebaseio.com");
        ref.unauth();
    };

  }
]);
```

However if I go to twitter again, in the same session, login and then come back again, the auth data shows on the page and in the console 3 times.

I cant be asking users to login twice, what is going on here?

Comment: I'm having the same problem, using `$authWithOAuthRedirect("facebook")` authentication. Using `$authWithOAuthPopup` works for me as well, but it's not my preferred way. Maybe `$authWithOAuthRedirect` is having issues in the AngularFire framework?

Comment: I'm pleased i'm not alone

Comment: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30900668/angularjs-firebase-need-to-login-twice-for-a-successful-login](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30900668/angularjs-firebase-need-to-login-twice-for-a-successful-login) This post has some useful info on this problem.